# Macbook air can't connect to wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, macbook-air

I have a macbook air (Mac OS X 10.6), I want to connect to a shared wifi,  my mac picks up the network but when I type the password (WPA Personal) it sends me an error message: time connection timed out! Knowing that I am in the first floor and the modem is on the ground floor and my friends can connect to the same network in my room with their pc's (Dell). I tried to delete the network from the list of preferred networks and keychain, disable and enable the airport and even reboot the modem but it doesn't work! I try to connect from a place closer to the modem (it picks up the wifi as if I'm in my room (2 dashes airport are filled)) I type the password and everything was perfect and the internet speed is excellent and when I returned to my room it asked me to type the password again and the same problem return however  I always use: remember this network! I don't know what to do and what comes from this problem! What should I do to resolve it because I need internet connection?

Comment: it's the wrong site to ask this kind of questions. do you even know what stack overflow means?

Comment: I know that it's a site where you can post your question about computer problems to have help !!

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions. use superuser.com for general computer problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider purchasing a Wifi range extender, which should give you a stable connection further away from the access point. From the way you describe the issue, sounds like that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you Adam, is there other solution to do? Preference options for example? Because sometimes it can connect for few minutes and then connection is interrupted. An other problem, i knew that there is an other modem Dlink witch is not far from my room and when i put my MBA near to this modem, the network doesn't appear in networks list !! MBA can't detect the WiFi !! I have had my mac for 3 years, I use WiFi networks normally and this is the first time that i face such case !!